# Iterating over a list in a regular expression replacement

Tags: regex, ant

I have a string with a prefix followed by list of at least one possibly empty suffix. The suffixes themselves are prefixed with a colon. Neither prefix nor suffix must contain any colon.

Example (1) for one empty suffix:

```
x:
```

Example (2) for two non empty suffixes ("a" and "b") and one empty suffix:

```
x:a::b
```

The [regular expression](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5B%5E%3a%5D%2b%29%28%3a%28%5B%5E%3a%5D%2a%29%29%2a&input=x%3aa%3a%3ab) for this pattern is:

```
([^:]+)(:([^:]*))*
```

The first match captures the prefix and the (3+2n)th match captures the suffixes (n = [0,1,2,...]).

In my replacement I would like to prefix each suffix. Example (1) should produce:

```
x
```

And example (2) should produce:

```
xa
x
xb
```

How do I have to specify the replacement expression?

My problem is, that the first replacement eats the prefix. And after that the second replacement does not see the prefix any more. I have to preserve the prefix for the remaining replacements. How can this be done?

Comment: I dont understand: "In my replacement I would like to prefix each suffix" - prefix each suffix with what?

Comment: @Richard It is written in the first sentence: "I have a string with a prefix followed ...". In the example x is the prefix.

Comment: What flavour of regex? What language or tools?

Comment: @M42 Ant´s [replaceregex](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replaceregex) in a [tokenfilter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#tokenfilter).

Answer (score 1):

I think I would extract the prefix first, and then do the replacement second.  It'll make the code easier to read, and it should be an easy replace at that point.

Comment: As far as I can see [Ant´s tokenfilter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#tokenfilter) has no memory to store the result of the first match.

Comment: I agree with Kieveli here. I can't see a way to specify a replacement pattern when capturing the prefix.